# How to save CSV with all fields quoted?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-csv

The below code does not add the double quotes which is the default. I also tried adding # and single quote using option `quote` with no success. I also used `quoteMode` with `ALL` and `NON_NUMERIC` options, still no change in the output.

```
s2d.coalesce(64).write
  .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
  .option("header", "false")
  .save(fname)
```

Are there any other options I can try? I am using spark-csv 2.11 over spark 2.1.

Output it produces:

```
d4c354ef,2017-03-14 16:31:33,2017-03-14 16:31:46,104617772177,340618697
```

Output I am looking for:

```
“d4c354ef”,”2017-03-14 16:31:33”,”2017-03-14 16:31:46”,104617772177,340618697
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**tl;dr** Enable `quoteAll` option.

```
scala> Seq(("hello", 5)).toDF.write.option("quoteAll", true).csv("hello5.csv")
```

The above gives the following output:

```
$ cat hello5.csv/part-00000-a0ecb4c2-76a9-4e08-9c54-6a7922376fe6-c000.csv
"hello","5"
```

That assumes the `quote` is `"` (see [CSVOptions](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/datasources/csv/CSVOptions.scala#L90))

That however won't give you *"Double quotes around all non-numeric characters."* Sorry.

You can see all the options in [CSVOptions](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/datasources/csv/CSVOptions.scala) that serves as the source of the options for the CSV reader and writer.

p.s. `com.databricks.spark.csv` is currently a mere alias for `csv` format. You can use both interchangeably, but the shorter `csv` is preferred.

p.s. Use `option("header", false)` (`false` as boolean not String) that will make your code slightly more type-safe.

Answer (score 2):

In Spark 2.1 where the old CSV library has been inlined, I do not see any option for what you want in the `csv` method of `DataFrameWriter` as seen [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter).

So I guess you have to map over your data "manually" to determine which of the `Row` components are non-numbers and quote them accordingly. You could utilize a straightforward `isNumeric` helper function like this:

```
def isNumeric(s: String) = s.nonEmpty && s.forall(Character.isDigit)
```

As you map over your `DataSet`, quote the values where `isNumeric` is `false`.

Comment: Thanks. But I am not using the native spark library. I am using the Databricks spark-csv library. https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv

Comment: I know you are, but you should switch because it is deprecated as they note. Besides, they aren't quite two distinct things. The functionality has been absorbed into Spark, and your question proves why you should switch. Getting help on deprecated libraries will only get harder and harder.

Comment: its sad only quoteAll is available in spark 2.1. I am facing a similar issue where i need `quoteMode` in spark 2